# How do I find my project name in a Django project?

Tags: django, pycharm

I have a pycharm project and, presumably, a Django project. Perhaps they are one and the same, perhaps not - I'm unsure as to the distinction.

Anyway, in my settings.py file (which is in the root of  `project` directory, which is what I presume is my pycharm project) I have:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'dumpstown.urls'
```

Does that mean `dumpstown` is my project name? Or my pycharm project name? What is the distinction? Because I *also* have a folder called `dumpstownapp` and this has all my models.py and view.py files. I would have thought that `dumpstownapp` was the Django project, but I really don't know!

So, to be concise:

In this folder setup

```
folderA
    folderB
        views.py
        models.py
        <other stuff>
    templates folder
    settings.py
    <other stuff>
```

which is the "Django project name" ~ and by that I mean, if I have a UserProfile defined in my models.py (shown above) what would be the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` entry I'd need for it? I'm getting several understandings from the django docs - I'd assume

```
dumpstownapp.models.UserProfile
```

But from the docs I'd get

```
dumpstownapp.UserProfile
```

Or maybe my app is called dumpstown? and *then* what do I get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FolderA is the Django project folder, and folderB is the Django app folder.

I haven't used a UserProfile, but according to the docs ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) it should contain a string containing the Django app name and the model name separated by a dot, so `"dumpstownapp.UserProfile"` should be correct. If you show the error someone can probably give you better help..

Django documentation used to say that the parent of the project folder (i.e. the parent of folderA) should be on the path, but I believe that has been changed to also include the project folder itself (i.e. folderA) -- since it makes sharing of Django apps much easier.  PyCharm seems to assume that is the case, since pressing Alt+F7 to auto-add an import for a newly used module create an import statement that assumes folderA is on the import path (I'm a relative newcomer to PyCharm, and I'm using it on a project that started in the Django 0.96 era, so I might just have things set up wrong..)  But folderA is both the Django and the PyCharm project (the .idea file is where PyCharm stores its project data).

Answer (score 1):

In one of my django-app git-submodule projects I needed to find out the name of the Django project that django-app/library was used in. To that end, I tried to get the path of the file that was being executed, find my package in the path and take the folder above it. However, it turned out that on the production server the project was deployed in a folder with a different name (a standard name like `www` or something along those lines). So this way is not fully reliable.

So I ended up setting a `PROJECT` variable in the django settings file and using that instead.